# Valgrind fails when using helgrind (undefined symbol)

Tags: valgrind

Creating the most basic program:

```
int main(){ return 1; }
```

Compiling it:

```
g++ -std=c++17 test.c -o test.out
```

And trying to run helgrind:

```
valgrind --tool=helgrind ./test.out

==5269== Helgrind, a thread error detector
==5269== Copyright (C) 2007-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP et al.
==5269== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5269== Command: ./test.out
==5269==
./test.out: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so: undefined symbol: pthread_mutexattr_gettype
==5269==
==5269== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5269== Use --history-level=approx or =none to gain increased speed, at
==5269== the cost of reduced accuracy of conflicting-access information
==5269== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

My system:

```
Completely updated to the latest version. 

Linux station 4.10.13-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 27 12:15:09 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux

local/glibc 2.26-6 (base)
    GNU C Library

local/valgrind 3.13.0-3
    A tool to help find memory-management problems in programs

ldd valgrind
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd577c5000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f538e16b000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055f1d6602000)
```

Why? Can you reproduce this behavior?

**EDIT:**
I have tried another version of vagrant, but in a fast way (because I have many programs/libs depending on libc-2.26). I installed valgrind 3.12.0 (removing the required libc-2.26 dep), and copied libc-2.25 to /usr/lib. Now, it runs `valgrind --tool=helgrind ls` without that error, but another binary (the real program that I wanted to use with valgrind) fails with the same error:

```
valgrind --tool=helgrind ./build/openclprog

==31334== Helgrind, a thread error detector
==31334== Copyright (C) 2007-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP et al.
==31334== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright
info
==31334== Command: ./build/openclprog
==31334== Selected platform: Intel(R) OpenCL sel_device changed to: 0
(to fit number of devices) Selected device: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2300
CPU @ 2.80GHz ./build/openclprog : symbol lookup error:
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so: undefined symbol:
pthread_mutexattr_gettype
==31334==
==31334== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31334== Use --history-level=approx or =none to gain increased speed,
at ==31334== the cost of reduced accuracy of conflicting-access information
==31334== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Differences in ldd between ls and openclprog:

/usr/bin/ls:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd9f936000)
libcap.so.2 => /usr/lib/libcap.so.2 (0x00007ff40d2a3000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff40ceeb000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff40d6d3000)
```

openclprog:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc78bde000)
libOpenCL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so.1 (0x00007fc5e5173000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc5e4deb000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc5e4a9b000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc5e4883000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc5e44cb000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc5e42c3000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(0x00007fc5e55bb000)
```

I tried to build openclprog in C++11 and C++17 and in both cases fail.

Also, I tried in another computer with a different CPU and GPU (but
still AMD) and gives the same error (valgrind 3.12.0).

Comment: I can't reproduce this on CentOS 6.6 with a fairly fresh build of valgrind from source. Perhaps your Arch Linux has broken something. Can you try building Valgrind from source?

Comment: @PaulFloyd I have installed valgrind-git r15940.0a5ff8c30-1 (3.14.0-GIT) and gives me the same error. I have both CPU and GPU with AMD. In another Arch with same brand but different model of CPU/GPU, the same problem. I updated the post with more info.

Answer (score 0):

What should be happening is

- Valgrind sets LD_PRELOAD to load the helgrind vgpreload
- This will then replace things like the system malloc and pthread functions

According to strace (running `strace -o vg.log ./tools/valgrind/bin/valgrind --tool=helgrind ./test.out` then filtering on the `open` calls), libpthread does not get opened.

ldd says that the vgpreload is not linked to any other shared libraries

```
ldd /home/paulf/tools/valgrind/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so
        statically linked
```

nm says that pthread_mutexattr_gettype is undefined in the vgpreload

```
nm
/home/paulf/tools/valgrind/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so | grep pthread_mutexattr_gettype
                 U pthread_mutexattr_gettype
```

OK, so the symbol is undefined but it loads OK on my system.

I just did a bit of poking around with LD_PRELOAD, some more googling and reading of the ld.so man page. According to this manpage, functions don't get resolved until they are referenced. I can reproduce the load error outside of valgrind if I run

```
LD_BIND_NOW=1 LD_PRELOAD=/home/paulf/tools/valgrind/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so /home/paulf/test.out
/home/paulf/test.out: symbol lookup error: /home/paulf/tools/valgrind/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so: undefined symbol: pthread_mutexattr_gettype
```

So, finally, could you check that you have no "LD_" environment variables set, and in particular LD_BIND_NOW.

Comment: `strings /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so | grep pthread_mutex` gives me this: `pthread_mutexattr_gettype` and others...

The system has libc.2.26.so. By enabled you mean if I can use `LD_PRELOAD=other.so valgrind...`? In that case, It is enabled. Because if I do `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libc-2.25.so valgrind...` it fails with the latest vagrind (it expects libc-2.26).